# Blowing-up along few points and embedding

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, blow-ups

Hello all.

Let
$X_{p_0,\ldots,p_n}\subset\mathbb{P}^N=\mathbb{P}^N_{\mathbb{C}}$ 
be the sequence of blowing-ups 
$\pi:\mathrm{Bl}_{p_0,\ldots,p_n}\longrightarrow\mathbb{P}^n$ 
along $n+1$ points of $\mathbb{P}^n$ (maybe infinitely near points), 
embedded by very ample divisor $H_X\sim d\pi^{\ast}(H_{\mathbb{P}^4})-E_1-\cdots - E_n$ 
($E_1,\ldots,E_n$ the exceptional divisors, 
$H_{\mathbb{P}^4}\in|\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^4}(1)|$, $d\geq 1$).

If $p_0' ,\ldots, p_n'$ is another list of $n+1$ points 
that produces $X_{p_0',\ldots,p_n'}$ as above,
is true that $X_{p_0,\ldots,p_n}, X_{p_0',\ldots,p_n'}$ are projectively equivalent ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You might want to add some "general position" condition on the points, otherwise the two manifolds that you get are not even biholomorphic. For example take $n=2$: if the $3$ points are collinear then the resulting blowup is not Fano, but if they are not collinear it is.

Comment: And if the points are in general position then the two  varieties are isomorphic, since $Aut({\mathbb P}^n}$ acts transitively on sets of $n+1$ points in general position. 

Comment: This should be clear if the points are not infinitely near... If the points are not in general position then my statement should depend da $\dim(⟨p_0,…,p_n⟩)$.